# Java String Comparisons

Tags: java, string, udp

I've been running into a very strange problem while working on a UDP based java project. To sum it up, when I receive a request through a DataPacket I convert it into a new string, then when I go to check the string value it continues to return false. The code is below.

```
        DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        aSocket.receive(request);
        String message = new String(request.getData());
        System.out.println("Received: " + new String(request.getData()));
        System.out.println(message); //Prints out "11" without quotes when I send it
        String a = "11";
        System.out.println("Received: " + message);
        if(message.equals("11")){
            System.out.println("Got 11.");
        }  
// Also tried .equals(a), but either ways it seems to be returning false.
```

Comment: Nothing strange -- your String is not "11". Have you checked the individual chars in the received String? The non-printing chars? The white space? Have you trimmed the String first before comparing it?

Comment: Try running a debugger and see what message equals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to trim your message maybe it contains space.

```
    DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
    aSocket.receive(request);
    String message = new String(request.getData()).trim();
    System.out.println("Received: " + new String(request.getData()));
    System.out.println(message); //Prints out "11" without quotes when I send it
    String a = "11";
    System.out.println("Received: " + message);
    if(message.equals("11")){
        System.out.println("Got 11.");
    }
```

Comment: This worked! Didn't notice but it seems like white space was the problem! Thank you